# "Undefined class" as argument for is_base_of

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

```
class Base {};

template <class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type>
class B {};                                                ^^^^^^^^^^ error C2139: 'A': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_base_of'

class A : public Base
{
    B<A> b;
};
```

Apparently this is not allowed. Is there a workaround, or something I'm forgetting?

Comment: I can immediately come up with a solution to the actual problem, but either way you're going to want to change the default argument value to `typename std::enable_if<...>::type`.

Comment: Why would I do that?

Comment: @T.J.Evers `std::enable_if` itself will never SFINAE out, it's its `type` member that is dynamically disabled.

Comment: Also, typo in my original comment: "I can ..." should have been "I can't ..." :).

Comment: Current workaround: us ```B<A, void> b;``` to bypass the detection. Not pretty, but at least it's still active everywhere else.

Comment: @Darhuuk the answer there does state that my problem is indeed not allowed... I'll stick with my workaround then, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the output for GCC:

> ```
> type_traits:1302:66: error: incomplete type 'A' used in type trait expression
>     : public integral_constant<bool, __is_base_of(_Base, _Derived)>
>                                                                  ^
> <source>:5:51: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::is_base_of<Base, A>' requested here
> template <class T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>>
>                                                   ^
> <source>:10:5: note: in instantiation of default argument for 'B<A>' required here
>     B<A> b;
>     ^~~~
>
> <source>:8:7: note: definition of 'A' is not complete until the closing '}'
> class A : public Base
>       ^
> ```

Indeed, `A` is incomplete until the closing `}` has been reached. You use `A` in the type traits while instantiating `B<A>` inside `A`, so you're out of luck there.

What you can do instead is to enforce it with a static_assert in a member function of `B`:

```
template <class T>
class B {
public:
    B() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "T must inherit from base");
    }
};
```

Inside member functions, all types are complete.